# Move project to a different organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Has anyone experience with moving a project (GKE, Cloud SQL, Cloud Storage, Private IPs, etc.) to a different organization?

I found some documentation but its limited in describing what actually can be moved so I'm looking for people with experience in this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Super Admin for both organization, Organization(A) and Organization(B) must be setup the required permissions necessary also the API to migrate the project.

1. Give the email account the Project Mover (*access to update and move projects) role on the Project to be moved.
2. Give the email account the Project Creator role on the destination Organization
   **If moving in folder > Project Mover on the Organization
3. On the Source and Destination Organizations, you will need the roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin (Organization Policy Admin) role or you can just give the email account the Organization Admin role for both Organizations
4. Check below constraints (this is in IAM & Admin > Organization Policies):

   a. Source Org > Allow constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations

   b. Destination Org > Allow constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources
5. Then issue this command in Cloud Shell once all the above requirements are met:

```
gcloud beta projects move [Project-ID] --organization [ORG-ID]
```

OR

```
gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID \
    --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
```

See this [documentation on project migration](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) and [documentation for project migration checklist](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration-checklist).

Comment: Yes I found this as well but I'm unable to understand from the documentation if e.g. private IPs are supported

Comment: Project Migration is simply a change in metadata, nothing should be impacted.

Comment: **Super Admin** does not exist in Google Cloud. That is a Workspace feature.

Answer (score 0):

its all well documented and infact there is no downtime to any of the components at the time of migration , imp thing is the org policies and any other customized iam roles that are applied at org or folder hierarchy will not move . so make sure to have the same set of org policies on the destination as well and create customized iam roles . one more important thing is handling special cases , make sure you have the proper work around if you have any special cases like Shared VPC ,OAuth consent screen  or others mentioned in the documentation